# How to get the direction of a selection in a RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

A text in a `RichTextBox` a user can select text forward or backward. How can I determine the direction of the selection programmatically? (The `LogicalDirection` of `End` and `Start` does not indicate this)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare the `CaretPosition` to the current `Selection` to determine from which direction the text was selected:

```
TextPointer caretPos = richTextBox.CaretPosition;
TextPointer selectStart = richTextBox.Selection.Start;
TextPointer selectEnd = richTextBox.Selection.End;

if(caretPos.CompareTo(selectStart) == 0)
{
    //The text was selected from right to left.
}
else if(caretPos.CompareTo(selectEnd) == 0)
{
    //The text was selected from left to right.
}
```